# EF Code First ASP.NET C# Design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to use EF Code first to create a database but I am not sure how to define the classes for the following relationship so that it is efficient.

We have a User and User has Friends, which in turn is a collection of User, so I was thinking of the following POCO Class

```
`//Class User
public class User
{
  public Guid UserId{get;set;}
  public string UserName{get;set;}
  public String UserAddress{get;set;}
  // other user properties
}

//Class Friend
public class Friend
{ 
  public Guid FriendId{get;set;} //unique identifier for Friend Table
  public virtual User CurrentUser{get;set;}
  public List<User> lstUserFriends {get;set;} //contains list of all friends that the     user has

}`
```

Does this look good performance-wise or do you think you can suggest an alternative?

Comment: It looks a bit strange to me... What is Friend? What not make "Friends" a property of User? (self referencing foreign key)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just do

```
public class User
{
  public Guid UserId{get;set;}
  public string UserName{get;set;}
  public String UserAddress{get;set;}
  public IList<User> Friends{get;set;}
  // other user properties
}
```

Comment: This seems to be only create one to one relation ship between each user as it has MembermemberId column created on each member row within the same table.

Answer (score 3):

You need self referencing many-to-many relation because use can have many friends but also can be friend of many users.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public String UserAddress { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Friends")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> FriendWith { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("FriendWith")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set;} 
}
```

Or you can omit `InverseProperty` data annotation and use fluent mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Friends)
                .WithMany(f => f.FriendWith);
    // I'm not sure but you can also need to add this:
    //          .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, you just saved me a couple of hours.